# plotting just the Hawaiian Islands

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I would like to plot just the Hawaiian Islands using Rstudio. I have tried ggmap and ggplot2. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

```
library(ggplot2)  
library(maps)  
all_states <- map_data("state")  
p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=all_states, 
                             aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),
                             color="white", fill="lightgreen" ) + 
                geom_point(  data=mapdata, aes(x=long, y=lat), color="red") + 
                geom_text(   data=mapdata, aes(long, lat, label = mapdata$Location), 
                             hjust = -.10,  size=3, angle = 15, color = "black")
```

Comment: Hi Marie! Welcome to SO. Can you show us (with code) what you tried?

Comment: I have used the code above for previous plotting of the whole US, but when i tried modifying it for just the hawaii islands, it does not receive the data needed

Comment: See this post https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fiftystater/vignettes/fiftystater.html - the problem is that the maps in the `maps` package only include the contiguous states.  The `fiftystater` package gets around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Andrew's suggestion, you can also try the package `"usmap"`, it includes Hawaii.

Try

```
install.packages("usmap")
library(usmap)

usmap::plot_usmap(include = c("HI"))
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/usmap/vignettes/mapping.html for more details on how to modify the map.